# Find Sugar ORM Record in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sugarorm

I have `Advertiser` class which extends `SugarRecord` in Kotlin:

```
class Advertiser : SugarRecord<Advertiser> {
    var number: String? = null
    var name: String? = null

    constructor() {}

    constructor(number: String, name: String) {
        this.number = number
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

when I try to find records by Java it works fine:

```
   Advertiser advertiser =  Advertiser.find(Advertiser.class, "number = ?", "123123").get(0);
```

but when I convert this code to Kotlin I face problem:

[image]

**how can I perform find in Kotlin?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call it this way

```
SugarRecord.find(Advertiser::class.java, "number = ?", "123123").get(0)
```